# SOAP Message size it greater than allowed limit [SECURITY.MSGSIZE v 1.0]? How?

Tags: python, soap, policy, rule

I'm trying to help a colleague run [SOATest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soatest) (a web services client that makes testing SOAP services easy) on a WCF web service operation, and for "big" responses, we are seeing this error:

```
SOAP Message size it greater than allowed limit [SECURITY.MSGSIZE v 1.0]
```

This is perplexing, as the tool is actually able to get a response from the server that contains no SOAP faults. Furthermore, the response isn't very big at all - 22kb to be exact. I can't seem to Google this error message, and the the grammar/spelling mistake in it isn't working for my benefit either.

Is this a SOATest setting? Maybe a WCF setting? Or a WS-Security setting? It certainly isn't a restriction we are imposing at the server level.

Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFfJP.png) for posterity.

Comment: Hahaha, a SOAtest.. if you would be Dutch, that would be really funny.

Comment: Ahh, yes it is :) http://translate.google.com/#nl|en|soa%20test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to get an answer to this error on the [SOATest forums](http://forums.parasoft.com/index.php?showtopic=2169).

SECURITY.MSGSIZE is one of the default SOAP Policy rule checks available to be added to a response. Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsmL2.png) of the particular rule as it was being applied. This particular rule is located at:

```
C:\Program Files\Parasoft\SOAtest\5.5.3\rules\SOAP\SECURITY.MSGSIZE.rule
```

If you open the default policy configuration package located at:

```
C:\Program Files\Parasoft\SOAtest\5.5.3\rules\soa.policy
```

you can then disable or modify the value of the SECURITY.MSGSIZE rule by if you right click on SOAP->Avoid large SOAP messages [SECURITY.MSGSIZE]->Edit->Method:

```
def checkSize(value, context):
    message = XMLUtil.serialize(value)
    size = len(message)
    if size > 10240:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

The `size > 10240` conditional is where this rule can be changed as needed. Or you could simply uncheck it as part of the default policy package and save the change that way instead.